# Can my Droid MAXX NOT delete everything if someone enters in the wrong password 10 times?

Tags: password, motorola-droid, delete

Recently someone was messing with my phone when they shouldn't have been, most likely playing with the password screen (I use the pattern thing with nine dots), and my phone factory reset.

I'm trying to find a way to password-protect my phone so that no random kid at school can access my email, but I don't need to be secure against North Korea trying to hack into it with brute force. I would prefer if this is possible in vanilla (obviously) but if there is a *free* app required, then that's okay too.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: To close-voters: this is perfectly on topic. It's asking for a way to achieve this natively (preferred), so it's not "is there an app for X".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found exactly what I'm looking for in vanilla Android: Settings > Security & Screen Lock > Device Administrators > Local Wipe Policy > Deactivate

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing built-in to Android currently. However, you might wish to take a look at [AutoErase](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.tokyo.firmapp.autoerasetrial):

> - When the number of failed unlock attempts reaches the limit that you specified, AutoErase will reset the device to factory default and erase all user data.
> - When the unlock attempts fail, messages warning that the device will be erased after certain number of unsuccessful attempts, will be displayed on the lock screen at the timing of your choice.

A pure [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset) is nothing super-secure, as with some knowledge and the right tools content can be recovered – but certainly enough "so that no random kid at school can access my email" (as it's unlikely that random kid has the required knowledge *and* tools at hand when at school).

A comparable tool would be [Wiper](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bsecure.wiper.lite), in case *AutoErase* doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: I can see it now: Somebody finds out you have the AutoErase installed and purposely fails at the unlock attempts just to erase your data.……but a jtag and some knowledge, then all the info on that device is theirs. Good links +1

Comment: To the point, @HasH_BrowN – which is why I at least would disable the "warning on the lock screen" to not raise suspicion :)

Comment: That sure would be an option to have disabled. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you can use a different locker app like Next from Microsoft, disable the normal lock sreen and set a PIN or pattern in Next.